# How to target a HTML helper RadioButtonFor in a tab structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am attempting to make a set of Radio Buttons accessible by tab index. The problem I am facing is that I cannot target RadioButtonFor helper with the Tab Index function

```
<div class="col-sm-12 app-label-text">
                @if (Model.Member == null)
                {
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.foo, "true", Yes)<text> Yes &nbsp; &nbsp;</text>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.foo, "false", No)<text> No</text>
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((bool)Model.foo.Value)
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.foo, "true", YesChecked)<text> Yes &nbsp; &nbsp;</text>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.foo, "false", No)<text> No</text>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.foo, "true", Yes)<text> Yes &nbsp; &nbsp;</text>
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.foo, "false", NoChecked)<text> No</text>
                    }
                }
            </div>
```

I would prefer to do this with a DRY jquery call that targets these without having to target individual Id's if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the variables "Yes", "No", etc. are of `Dictionary` 
You can add the [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) attribute, it works for me.

```
Yes.Add("tabindex", 0);
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ksaWS)

Comment: Thank you very much, This works perfectly, I realized later that the issue was that I was trying to target an element that can be enabled, but was disabled at that time.